# How to sort a javascript array of numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to sort an array in javascript..

anyone how to do that??

by default the sort method doesn't work with numbers...

I mean:

```
a = [1, 23, 100, 3]
a.sort()
```

a values are:

```
[1, 100, 23, 3]
```

thanks :)

Comment: `a.sort(function(a,b){return a-b;})` [Here's a link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to some docs. You should become accustomed to doing research on your own. It will only help you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Usually works for me:

```
a.sort((a, b) => a - b);
```

Comment: Concise and to the point using simple maths and `>1 = 1 && <-1 = -1` : )

Answer (score 3):

So if you write the sorting function, it will work.

```
[1, 23, 100, 3].sort(function(a, b){
    if (a > b)
        return 1;
    if (a < b)
        return -1;
    return 0
});
```

Comment: Note, the comparison function can return any value it likes -- only the sign is important.  So the whole function could be reduced to `return a - b;`.

Comment: You are right. This a general purporse solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function sortNumber(a,b)
{
return a - b;
}

var n = ["10", "5", "40", "25", "100", "1"];
document.write(n.sort(sortNumber));

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in a comparator function to `sort`.

```
> a.sort(function(a, b) { return a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0; });
  [1, 3, 23, 100]
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a [custom sort function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

```
a = [1, 23, 100, 3];
a.sort(function(a,b){ return a-b; });
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is a solution to sort a Javascript array in ascending order

**code**

```
    function bubblesort(array){
        var done = false;
        while(!done){
            done = true;
            for(var i = 1; i< array.length; i++){
                if(array[i -1] > array[i]){
                    done = false;
                    var tmp = array[i-1];
                    array[i-1] = array[i];
                    array[i] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
        return array;
    }
    var numbers = [2, 11, 1, 20, 5, 35];

    bubblesort(numbers);
```