# Sort array in ascending order based on ints and not strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array with this structure:

```
myArray = [ [<number>, [<string>] ], [<number>, [<string>] ], ... ];
```

I'd like to sort the array according to the ints. 
Unfortunately, when I call .sort() on myArray it returns me an array sorted according to the strings.
How could I solve this?

Comment: Mix [Sorting objects in an array by a field value in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sorting-objects-in-an-array-by-a-field-value-in-javascript) with [sort a javascript array of numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9438814/1048572) (didn't found the exact dupe of this)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
myArray.sort(function(a,b) {return a[0]-b[0]})
```

Answer (score 0):

To perform a numeric sort, you must pass a function as an argument when calling the sort method.

```
var myarray=[[21,"aadfa"], [24,"ca"],[52,"aa"], [15,"ba"]]
myarray.sort(function(a,b){return a[0] - b[0]})
```

you can find more information about it on 
http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/arraysort.shtml

The function specifies whether the numbers should be sorted ascending or descending.

Here you have more examples http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

Comment: I didn't see your answer, I've just noticed that it is multidimensional array and my answer was for one dimension array :) Also pointing to making function that gets two objects to compare is good advice and from that point it is not hard to figure out how to write comparing function.